# Get value from previous Cmdlet in the pipeline

Tags: powershell, pipeline

I got the following command:
`Get-Mailbox | Get-MailboxPermission  | Select-Object Identity,User,AccessRights | Format-Table -AutoSize`.
I want to be able to get the `PrimarySMTPAddress` value from the previous pipe where I got the results for the `Get-Mailbox`.
At the moment when I add the property `PrimarySMTPAddress` I receive nothing in the column.

The final result should like this:

```
Identity                       User     AccessRights     PrimarySMTPAddress
--------                       ------   ------------     ------------------
Domain.local/Users/Mailbox1    User1    {FullAccess}     Mailbox1@Domain.local
Domain.local/Users/Mailbox2    User2    {FullAccess}     Mailbox2@Domain.local
Domain.local/Users/Mailbox3    User3    {FullAccess}     Mailbox3@Domain.local
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet, assign the value to a variable, then use `Write-Output` to send the pipeline value to the next cmdlet. When you use `Select-Object`, you can access the variable value with a calculated property.

```
Get-Mailbox | 
ForEach-Object { $primarySmtpAddress = $_.PrimarySMTPAddress; Write-Output $_; |
    Get-MailboxPermission | 
    Select-Object Identity,User,AccessRights, @{n='PrimarySMTPAddress';e={$primarySmtpAddress}}} | 
Format-Table -AutoSize
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the prompt answer, it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 4):

There's a common parameter "pipelinevariable" for that purpose.

```
Get-Mailbox -pipelinevariable mail | Get-MailboxPermission | 
  Select-Object Identity,User,AccessRights,
  @{n='PrimarySMTPAddress';e={$mail.PrimarySMTPAddress}} | 
  Format-Table -AutoSize
```